# Formato de hora que no se modifica con los cambios en la configuración regional

Tags: excel, vba

La ayuda sobre formatos numéricos de Excel no explica el uso de "@" al establecer el formato de fecha y hora. Parece que este modificador impide que el formato se modifique al cambiar la configuración regional. Alguien tiene documentación sobre su uso?
Por ejemplo, qué diferencia hay entre el formato "hh:mm" y "hh:mm;@"

Gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El formato "hh:mm;@" lo que hace es formatear la hora como texto. El dato se mostrará igual tanto en "hh:mm;@" como en "hh:mm" pero si necesitas hacer cálculos con las horas tendrás que utilizar "hh:mm".

Con "hh:mm;@", al estar en formato texto no es afectado por el cambio de configuración regional.

Comment: Gracias Dogwall, ahora lo comprendo. Un saludo.